# Optimizing Stored Procedure that uses multiple temp tables to join and output data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design

I am trying to optimize a stored procedure to improve overall performance. Currently the design has multiple temp tables with the last column designed to perform aggregate functions (such as SUM) on fields it draws data from.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL_Refunds (CurrencyID int, DateValue DATETIME, Refunds decimal(18,2))

CREATE TABLE #TBL_Fees (CurrencyID int, DateValue DATETIME, Fees decimal(18,2)) 

CREATE TABLE #TBL_Deposits (CurrencyID int, DateValue DATETIME, Deposits decimal(18,2)) 

CREATE TABLE #TBL_Cancellations (CurrencyID int, DateValue DATETIME, Cancellations decimal(18,2))
```

An example of one of the aggregate function performed on the last field of one of the temp tables looks like the following:

```
INSERT #TBL_Cancellations(currencyID, DateValue, Cancellations) 
    SELECT C.CurrencyID, C.Date, SUM(T.Amount) - SUM(T.Debit)
    FROM Currency C
    JOIN Transaction T ON C.CurrencyId = T.CurrencyId
    -- More conditions here . . .
    GROUP BY C.CurrencyId, C.Date
```

The final select outputs the aggregate field of each temp table and uses a LEFT JOIN to match each of them.

Eg.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    C.CurrencyCode 'Currency Code',
    C.ConversionRate 'Conversion Rate',
    R.Refunds,
    F.Fees 'Fees',
    D.Deposits 'Desposits'
    -- More here . . .
FROM 
    #TBL_Refunds (CurrencyID int, DateValue DATETIME, Refunds decimal(18,2)) R
LEFT JOIN 
    Currency C ON R.CurrencyID = C.CurrencyID
LEFT JOIN 
    #TBL_Fees F ON F.CurrencyID = C.CurrencyID
LEFT JOIN 
    #TBL_Deposits D ON D.CurrencyID = C.CurrencyID
-- More JOINS here. . .
```

Is there a better design to solve this problem without the use of temp tables? Is there a more modern approach to solve this problem?

I am relatively new to writing stored procedures and SQL, so any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: `Is there a better design to solve this problem` - which problem? Your pieces of SQL do not describe any of possible performance issues. The key to optimization is analysis of bottlenecks. Have you detected any?

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest you to use indexes on your temporary tables also because it seems that at the end you are using only select query to find the distinct records. and be sure that at end the you should either drop your temporary table or you indexes because next time they will take more time for their indexes rebuild.

I also prefer not use create statement for your temporary tables use insert into statement.

make sure you have the proper indexes on you the columns where you are performing these aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

What isn't performing well. Right away I would:

1. Model you aggregates as computed columns
2. use with tablockx on the inserts
3. SELECT 'DISTINCT' - why?
4. All LEFT OUTER JOINS - is this necessary?
5. No indexes on any CurrencyID in your tables, and for that matter
6. Why isnt this just combined to one table, or where are the natural keys in the tables? Are these really 1:1 relationships?

Comment: lmao rough crowd